# Storyboard drag and drop feature does not work for creating action

Tags: ios, xcode5, uistoryboard

I have UIView based class. Usually I use drag and drop feature for the buttons to create some action. So I open Storyboard and try drag and drop from the button touch up inside action to the code line. The blue binding line appears, but it does not offer to create new method in the code. I have checked name of class and it correspond to class in which I drag and drop but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you select the correct UIView from storyboard and assign the correct custom UIView sub class in Identity Inspector? If not xcode will not let you add methods like that.

Comment: My UIViewController contains UIView with custom class. The custom view has view(UIView) that contain UIButtons, but it does not want to work.

Comment: have you assigned your custom UIVIew sub-class to your view by selecting the view from storyboard and change it's 'custom class' field using Identity-Inspector?

Comment: yes, I have assigned it, I reload mac and everything works good.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to add that method? In viewcontroller OR in custom view class? Make sure your custom view in storyboard has same class name as your custom class.

Comment: yes the custom class name is correct. it works for example if i make drag and drop from the custom view in the scene list to my buttons, then I can choose some already written IBAction method, but if I drag to the line code (directly in the code field), it does not work

Comment: Check return type of your action it should be something like this - `-(IBAction)yourButtonClicked:(id)sender`

Comment: yes the action is IBAction that's why I can assign it to button via inside storyboard scene. When I make right click button then I see this actions and can drag and drop to some button, but can't drop it from the button to the code directly. I had some bug before, but when I rerun Xcode it worked good...